# Action Method in MVC.Net is not called by jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to call the Action method by using jquery but its not been returning any value although its been returning the in the success label.
code for jquery is as follow:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Test" />
```

```
 $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/GetDateTimeString",
            datatype: "text",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#pdata").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#pdata").html("ERROR");
            }
        });
    });
```

and the code for the aCcount controller where i add a method is as follow

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetDateTimeString()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

its not being called breakpoint is not being hitted.

Comment: First thing: You're using `<input type="submit">` Try using `type="button"` or prevent it's default action with `event.preventDefault`

Comment: did you wrap your code in `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: I tried your code in a sample mvc application. It is working fine. check your jquery reference, and better to use button type. if you are not using any form data.

Comment: Check whether you get any errors in the console (F12 -> Console)

Comment: Make sure you have added all the required jQuery files

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the form from being submitted with this code

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function (ev) {
        //prevent form from submit
        ev.preventDefault();
        // Not process ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/GetDateTimeString",
            datatype: "text",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#pdata").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#pdata").html("ERROR");
            }
        });
    });
```

Read the comments, @DhavalMarthak already had this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ExecuteAjax(URL,data,sucess) {
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (sucess != null && typeof sucess === "function")
            sucess(data);
    });
}

 (function () {
 ExecuteAjax("/Home/MultipleJoin", null, function (data) {
     $("#grid tr.rowtr").remove();
     fillGrid(data);
 });
})();
```

Make sure spelling are correct and  js reference and type=button